# Ember JS - Component vs. Factory

Tags: ember.js

I am very new to Ember JS, and I even have to admit that it is my very first framework I use.

Well. I am facing a design problem. I want to make an audio webapplication which will at all time need to be able to play audio, and therefore I want to make an `AudioPlayer` singleton that will be available in the app's entire lifespan.

According to Ember's documentation on [Dependency Injection](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/applications/dependency-injection/) I could just register a *factory*, which by default is registered as singleton, and I could access it by all time via:

```
applicationInstance.lookup('audio:player'); // For example
```

This seems like an idea, but I also need an interface for the audio player, with knobs like play, pause and stop; HTML that is. Is that possible? To make a "view" for the factory?

The second possibility I see is making an `audio-player` *component*, but with the component I have to give up the singleton, and I really only want just one audioplayer on the site, which will also be the owner of the `AudioContext`, which is only needed once per site.

So. What should I do? Should I go with the factory or with the model?

---

PS: I want to think that I need a *controller*, but I have read in the Ember JS guide that it is soon to be deprecated.

Comment: One option is you can still use component that delivers the UI and this component can make use of a audioPlayer service which contains all the core functionality, and services are by default singleton.(https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/applications/services/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quickly implemented something for you, that expands on the comment by @Deewendra. You'll see the app consists of the two afformentioned parts.

The audio-player service in the services directory

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  ids: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
  songs: Ember.computed('ids',function(){
    return this.get('ids').map(id => {
        return { id: id, title: `Awesome Song ${id}`}
    })
  }),
  currentlyPlaying: '',
  currentIndex: 0,
  currentStatus: 'stopped',

  start() {
    this.setSongByIndex();
    this.set('currentStatus','playing');
  },
  stop(){
    this.set('currentStatus','stopped');
  },
  nextSong() {
    let maxIndex = this.get('ids.length') - 1;
    let currentIndex = this.get('currentIndex');
    let nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;

    if (nextIndex > maxIndex) {
        this.stop();
    } else {
        this.set('currentIndex',nextIndex);
        this.setSongByIndex();
    }
  },
  previousSong() {
    let maxIndex = this.get('ids.length') - 1;
    let currentIndex = this.get('currentIndex');
    let prevIndex = currentIndex - 1;

    if (prevIndex < 0) {
        this.stop();
    } else {
        this.set('currentIndex',prevIndex);
        this.setSongByIndex();
    }
  },
  setSongByIndex() {
    const songs = this.get('songs');
    const currentIndex = this.get('currentIndex');
    this.set('currentlyPlaying',songs[currentIndex]);
  }
});
```

An audio-player component

```
// components/audio-player.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  audioPlayer: Ember.inject.service('audio-player'),
  actions: {
    start() {
        this.get('audioPlayer').start();
    },
    stop() {
        this.get('audioPlayer').stop();
    },
    next(){
        this.get('audioPlayer').nextSong();
    },
    previous(){
        this.get('audioPlayer').previousSong();
    }
  }
});

// templates/components/audio-player
Song Title: {{audioPlayer.currentlyPlaying.title}} <br/>
Audio Player Status: {{audioPlayer.currentStatus}} <br/>
<button {{action 'start'}}>Start</button> |
<button {{action 'next'}}>Next</button> |
<button {{action 'previous'}}>Previous</button> |
<button {{action 'stop'}}>Stop</button> |
```

Which is connected to the service by using the Ember.inject.service() method.

As you'll see, the "state" of the player lives in the service, and the component interacts with it via a html/handlebars template, coupled with a javascript file equivalent to the name of the template, that will handle interactions between the "view"(template) and "state"(service).

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/27c09828d7b0f0b056a9b1a33b4f19f2?openFiles=templates.components.audio-player.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.audio-player.hbs) to click around in, and experiment.

I'm not sure what your experience is in regards to programming outside of "frameworks", in regards to web technologies etc, and thought twice about submitting this, but I think it should help more than it will hurt.

Comment: I was not yet really aware of services yet. Thankyou very much!

Comment: I advise to initialize properties, especially arrays and objects, in the `init` method. In this case it's not a problem because services are singletons, but it's a nice practice all the same.